# button onclick replace hours and minutes, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Can any body help me, the **button** replace **hours and minutes (HH:MM)** onclick.

`<button id="pressbtn1" onclick="getElementById('pressbtn1').innerHTML=Date()">Press</button>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: 1. it is document.getElementById but it is not needed when it is inline. 2. Please search for hh mm and you would have found `var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleTimeString();` to which you add `.slice(0,-3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.getHours()` and `.getMinutes()` like...

```html
<html>
<button id="pressbtn1" onClick="show()">Press</button>
<script>
 function show()
 {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
document.getElementById("pressbtn1").innerHTML  = h+":"+m;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: add `if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;` and 
        `if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;`
        _result Show: 02:09_